# 2 x 2 matrix game and expected value

Tags: soft-question, game-theory

I have found the optimal strategy for the row player and column player. How do I find the expected value of the game for the row player and determine whether the game is favourable to the row player or column player (or neither)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value for given mixed (random, independent) strategies is given by $\vec{r}^TM\vec{c}$, where the column vector $\vec{r}$ is the row player's mixed strategy (expressed as a vector of probabilities); $\vec{c}$ is the column player's strategy, and $M$ is the payoff matrix.

Typically payoffs are from the point of view of the row player, so a positive expected value is favorable to the row player; negative, to the column player.